# Going back from Storyboard ViewController to a previously used .xib ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have an app that runs through a sequence of view controllers. We'll diagram it like this:

```
IntroViewController -> MenuViewController -> Test1StoryBoard
                                          -> Test2ViewController
                                          -> Test3ViewController
```

Where there is an intro screen, then a menu screen where you can select Test1, Test2, or Test3. However, as this is a rather large app that was made by several people, I made Test 1 as a storyboard while the rest are .xibs. At the end of Test1, I want to go back to MenuViewController, so I used:

```
mVC = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:mVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This bit of code successfully takes the user back to MenuViewController. However, once we are back in MenuViewController, the buttons that would ordinarily take the user back to Test1, Test2, or Test3 do not work. There are no error messages, but nothing at all happens when they are clicked. I understand this question is a little vague and would be happy to provide more code if necessary, but can anyone shed any light on what the problem might be?

Comment: When you are going from Test1 to MenuVC, do not create new view controller again. Either call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` or call `popViewControllerAnimated:` method depending upon what you had used to present Test1 or Test2 or Test3. Also, can you post the code of the way you are instantiating Test1, test2 and test3 from MenuViewController.

Comment: @user1190882, you should re-post your comment as an answer. It is the correct answer, and then the OP should accept it. To the OP, using alloc/init creates a new copy of your menuViewController. Now you have 2, one that was set up before, and a brand-new one that is probably not configured correctly but is now stacked on top of your other view controllers. That's a mess.

Comment: Ok @DuncanC. Posting it as answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are going from Test1 to MenuVC, do not create new view controller again. Either call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` or call `popViewControllerAnimated:` method depending upon what you had used to present Test1 or Test2 or Test3 which is either  `presentViewController:animated:completion:` or `pushViewController:animated` respectively.